# What is BigData and NoSQL, any good books on both?

Tags: nosql, bigdata

I know I am asking two questions in one. But can someone please tell me what is meant by bigdata. Also how does NoSQL different from conventional SQL.

Lastly can you please recommend good/best books or tutorials/website on topic which can take a newbie to advance level.

Please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Big Data" is a buzz word, which means that it defines different (albeit related) things to different people.

Some use it for database software that specializes in "Big Data", some use it for whole infrastructure that manipulates large data sets, some use it for large data sets themselves (structured, semi-structured, and non-structured).

"Big Data" data sets posses at least one distinct property: due to their large size and/or lack of structure they are assumed to hide valuable information and relationships. The end goal of about every "Big Data" project is uncovering these valuable knowledge in efficient and repeatable manner.

How large is "Big Data"? Large enough that few years ago it would demand million dollar investments in all 3: hardware, software and development. Today you may still require a significant (but less) investment but probably just into 2 out of these 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for resources books on these which will teach a newbie and take them from novice to advance level.

Comment: No book alone will take anyone from novice to advanced level but some can help tremendously. I have no knowledge of good NoSQL books but picking up something from O'Reilly almost never a bad idea.